# ListView no muestra los datos a pesar de que no hay error-Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

No se está produciendo ningún error (tras revisar Run y Logcat)pero los datos de la base de datos no se muestran en la aplicación en el ListView. Las reglas de la base de datos son las siguientes:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}
```

El código es el siguiente:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_modified_medicine);

        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listMedicines);
        List<String>list= new ArrayList<>();
        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,listaMedicinas);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);



        mAddToDB=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAñadirMedicinaModified);
        mnombre=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_new_medicine_modified);
        mdosis=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.add_new_dosis_medicine);

        //declare the database reference object. This is what we use to access the database.
        //NOTE: Unless you are signed in, this will not be useable.
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();




puntoDeAcceso=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("Medicamentos").child(userID);

puntoDeAcceso.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                List<String>list=new ArrayList<>();
                for(DataSnapshot child:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    HashMap<String,Object>value=(HashMap<String, Object>) child.getValue();
                    String nombre=String.valueOf(value.get("nombre"));
                    String dosis=String.valueOf(value.get("dosis"));
                    System.out.println(nombre+dosis);
                    list.add(nombre+""+dosis);
                }
                    mListView.setAdapter(mediAdapter);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });



    }
```

Como he mencionado antes, aparentemente no se está produciendo ningún error pero no está funcionando el ListView. La base de datos ficticia y de ejemplo que estoy utilizando tiene el siguiente aspecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Qué es lo que puede estar ocurriendo? Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Revisaste en la consola si esto imprime los datos: `System.out.println(nombre+dosis);`? Tampoco veo de qué manera pasas los datos obtenidos al `ListView` ¿?

Comment: El problema es que nunca estas agregando los datos a la ListView, solo los estas imprimiendo por consola. La listaMedicinas siempre esta vacia, asi que no va a mostrar nada.

Comment: Acabo de darme cuenta de ello y he añadido la parte de código que faltaba. Sigue sin mostrarse aunque en la consola se imprimen los datos

Comment: @Montu mediAdapter no esta declarado en ningun lado y 'list' esta lleno de datos pero no lo usas para nada, ademas de eso te falta el notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba con esto, Luego de recoger todos los datos de firebase, no hagas otro setadapter, Cambia esa linea por.

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Con esa linea le dices al ArrayAdapter que se actualize ya que han habido cambios.
Y otra cosa, fijate bien es los nombres de las variables ya que veo que el arrayList donde guardas los datos se llama List pero en que pones en el ArrayAdapter se llama listaMedicina, asi que al parecer le estas enviando una lista Vacia.